# Is there any official reference to the story Julia Ecklar's "The Hand of God" is based on (if it is based on one)?

Tags: story-identification, music, post-apocalyptic

I'm trying to find out what story "The Hand of God" by Julia Ecklar (lyrics here: http://mindstalk.net/filk/handofgod) is based on. The song is from her 1986 album Divine Intervention.

The details are specific enough that it seems like it must be based on something. I've done a bunch of Google searching for "The Hand of God" with keywords like "story" and "based on" but have had no luck. Prometheus Music doesn't seem to have that sort of info.

Has she said anywhere what it's based on? Or, failing that, are there any similar stories out there that might be the basis for the song?

Comment: This might be a speculative question, because there may not be an actual answer for it; i.e. she may never have said what it is based on.

Comment: Edited to try to make it less speculative. (I'd like to know the actual answer, but I'll take speculation too.)

Comment: Much better question. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's answered in the album liner notes:

http://www.prometheus-music.com/print/Divine%20Intervention%20Booklet.pdf

Comment: Well, that's a logical place for it! Somehow I missed that. Thanks very much!!